# Possible to create an index on a label in py2neo?

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I was wondering if it is possible to create an index on a label in py2neo? Like the Cypher:  "CREATE INDEX ON :Person(name)"?

I think this is something that was added in Neo4j 2.0, so it might not be implemented in py2neo yet?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to manage label indices from py2neo, take a look at the [Schema](http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/schema/) chapter. I think py2neo generally wraps cypher queries, so I would think the methods for schema management are equivalent to the different cypher schema statements.

And you can always [execute your own queries](http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/cypher/) directly, so anything you can do in cypher you can do in py2neo.

Comment: Py2neo actually uses the REST API for most of its functions and only wraps Cypher for features that aren't otherwise available. In this case, the functions in the Schema chapter use the REST API but should be equivalent to the Cypher variants, as indicated.

Comment: Thanks both, I got it working. I actually think my major problem was that I could not refer to created nodes and relationships, that I created in a batch using appended Cypher.

Comment: would you mind updating the links to the py2neo book?